# Insert formula in IF statement?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure this out and can't seem to.  Is it possible for me to write a IF statement in google sheets that will insert a formula if the data is matches?

`=if('2018'!I:I="Tomatoes",='2018'!J2," ")`. This is the formula that I want. I have a Google Form that is set up for people to preorder produce. I want to pull data onto one sheet for each thing they select.  If I put it in quotes it does it as text not a formula

Comment: What do you mean by 'data is correct'. I'd suggest you give some context and what you have already tried

Comment: Are you expecting the returned formula to work i.e. to be evaluated or just a string returned?

Comment: =if('2018'!I:I="Tomatoes",='2018'!J2," "). This is the formula that I want.  I have a google form that is set up for people to preorder produce.  I want to pull data onto one sheet for each thing they select.

Comment: So add the info to your original question - people are not going to trawl through all the comments to find info...

Answer (score 3):

*Yes, it absolutely **is** possible!*

Simply use this function:

```
IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

***<sub>...where:</sub>***

- **`logical_expression`** is an expression that evaluates to `True` when the data is correct, or `False` when the data is incorrect.
- **`value_if_true`** is the formula that should be used if the data is correct.
- **`value_if_false`** is the formula or value that you want to use when the data is incorrect.  For example, you could use `"incorrect!"` or have it display nothing by using an empty string (`""`)

---

### More information:

- Youtube: **[Google SheetsFormulas with If, Then, Else, Else If Statements](https://youtu.be/hG5vKMb0Lpo)**
- Google Docs Support : **[`IF` Function documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)**